# How to customize Antd Tree inter drag and drop of tree nodes

Tags: reactjs, tree, treeview, antd

Please read the issue below,
I have 3 levels of hierarchy in the tree, Node, Subnode and child. My requirements are

1. Drop Node only on node level, which means Node should not be dropped under subnode and child.
2. Drop Subnode only on Subnode level, which means it should avoid dropping Subnode as a Node and child. But subnode can be dropped under any Node or inter dropped on same node.
3. Similarly, Drop Children  only on children level, which means it should avoid dropping children as a Node and subnode. But children can be dropped under any Subnode or inter dropped on same subnode.

Currently my tree is any node anywhere, attaching sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-antd-5-1-7-forked-hej1f9?file=/demo.js

Any help would be appreciated.